# Unity3D game freezes when sending an API request

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using an [open-source game](https://github.com/federicodangelo/CubeWorld) to write a script, that captures the screen frames in a collection and sends the collection to an API server.

Capturing works fine, but as soon as the API request fires, the game freezes for ~500ms. If I understand correctly, this request blocks the main thread.

I've tried to send the request in a different thread, but get some weird errors.

How can I send requests in a background, so it doesn't block the main thread?

Here's my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class Recorder : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float captureInterval = 1f / 24f;
    private readonly List<string> frames = new();

    async void Update()
    {
        if (Time.timeSinceLevelLoad >= captureInterval)
        {
            StartCoroutine(CaptureFrame());

            captureInterval = Time.timeSinceLevelLoad + (1f / 24f);

            if (frames.Count >= 120)
            {
                StartCoroutine(CommitFrames(frames));

                frames.Clear();
            }
        }
    }

    IEnumerator CaptureFrame()
    {
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();

        Texture2D texture = ScreenCapture.CaptureScreenshotAsTexture();
        byte[] jpg = texture.EncodeToJPG();
        string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(jpg);

        frames.Add(base64);

        Destroy(texture);
    }

    IEnumerator CommitFrames(List<string> framesData)
    {
        var payload = new CommitFramesData() { frames = framesData };

        var www = CreateRequest("http://my-api.test/api/frames", RequestType.POST, payload);

        yield return www.SendWebRequest();

        www.Dispose();
    }

    private UnityWebRequest CreateRequest(string path, RequestType type = RequestType.GET, object data = null)
    {
        var request = new UnityWebRequest(path, type.ToString());

        if (data != null)
        {
            var bodyRaw = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonUtility.ToJson(data));
            request.uploadHandler = new UploadHandlerRaw(bodyRaw);
        }

        request.downloadHandler = new DownloadHandlerBuffer();
        request.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

        return request;
    }
}

public enum RequestType
{
    GET = 0,
    POST = 1,
    PUT = 2
}

[Serializable]
class CommitFramesData
{
    public List<string> frames;
}
```

Comment: Why is your `Update` async?

Comment: And no .. the request does not block  ... This is what does: `Texture2D texture = ScreenCapture.CaptureScreenshotAsTexture(); byte[] jpg = texture.EncodeToJPG();   string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(jpg);`

Comment: And whyyyy do you convert everything to base64 string .. just to then again serialize it into JSON? .. this is a huge data overkill... Why not stick to bytes? You are basically blowing up the size into the base64 string and in the end the JSON is anyway again converted into bytes in order to transmit the request... Should rather change your backend to properly handle Multipart frame requests and send the images directly from byte[]

Comment: @derHugo I must've left `async` from the old code, I was trying to find a workaround. Thanks for the answer, I'll try to send bytes instead of base64 and see if it will keep freezing

Comment: probably will yes.. doing that `EncodeToPng` is most probably the most expensive bit.. Unity API at this level isn't really made to stream the rendering..

Comment: It helped, thanks a lot! But right now I don't get any data on the backend. I've added `www.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");`. Should I still be using the `var bodyRaw = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonUtility.ToJson(data));` encoding in the CreateRequest function?

Comment: I still want to send a collection to reduce the amount of requests on the backend

Comment: What I meant is you shouldn't be going through a JSON at all but go through [`MultiFormFileSection`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.MultipartFormFileSection.html) see also e.g. https://answers.unity.com/questions/1632065/how-to-upload-multiple-files-to-a-server-using-uni.html